# Troubleshooting USGS fetch tool?

Tags: data, usgs

Goal: I am attempting to create a fetch (wind exposure) raster for a portion of the St. Lawrence River in order to look at habitat suitability for a number of fish species.

Tool used: http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/wind_fetch_wave_models_2012update.html

- Tool is zipped near the bottom of page and has a pdf w/ instructions below it.

Link to image of raster input: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bhuz.jpg

- After making that album I changed output location to a regular folder.

Wind Direction I am keeping simple to start:
230,100

My result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7VcI.jpg

- Everything is valued as 0???

Can anyone let me know why I am not getting pretty images like the ones in the PDF?

Additional Information:

-The location is the Thousand Islands at the intersection of Lake Ontario and the St. Lawrence River.

Comment: Hi I have the same problem, just wondering if you found the reason as to why? Thanks!

Comment: saw elsewhere it was a projection issue and trying this got it working with a map projection!